# Is there a language with constrainable types?

Tags: haskell, agda, dependent-type

Is there a typed programming language where I can constrain types like the following two examples?

1. A Probability is a floating point number with minimum value 0.0 and maximum value 1.0.

   ```
   type Probability subtype of float
   where
       max_value = 0.0
       min_value = 1.0
   ```
2. A Discrete Probability Distribution is a map, where: the keys should all be the same type, the values are all Probabilities, and the sum of the values = 1.0.

   ```
   type DPD<K> subtype of map<K, Probability>
   where
       sum(values) = 1.0
   ```

As far as I understand, this is not possible with Haskell or Agda.

Comment: I believe ADA has something like that (subtype constraints). e.g. http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~andy/lrm95/03_02_02.htm

Comment: You're looking for dependently-typed languages - types can depend on values.  Some examples include Idris, Agda, and Coq.

Comment: SQL definitely does this (See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

Comment: Hi, I work on LiquidHaskell (described in an answer below) and would be very curious (and grateful!) to see the program/application you're working on (in particular, the code where you'd like to preserve these constraints.) Thanks!

Comment: Shen (http://shenlanguage.org/) has this facility. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/qilang/3lAyZhxQ4sw/HtSJs9JXtEsJ for an example.

Comment: Ada (*not* "ADA") lets you define a type or subtype with a range constraint: `subtype Probability is Float range 0.0 .. 1.0;` or `type Probability is digits 7 range 0.0 .. 1.0;`. It doesn't let you impose arbitrary constraints, like requiring that all the values add up to `1.0`. Most OOish languages should let you define a opaque type whose operations enforce whatever constraints you like, but that's not the same as having the type itself define the constraints. Eiffel's class invariants *might* do what you want, but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you want is called [refinement types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_%28computing%29#Refinement_types).

It's possible to define `Probability` in Agda: [Prob.agda](https://github.com/crypto-agda/crypto-agda/blob/master/experimental/probabilities/Prob.agda)

The probability mass function type, with sum condition is defined at line 264.

There are languages with more direct refinement types than in Agda, for example [ATS](http://www.ats-lang.org/)

Comment: The difference between what I'd do in Agda or Coq vs. what this question asks for is that refinement types are *new* types, rather than subtypes of an existing type.  E.g., `DPD` would be a new type containing a map and some proofs, rather than a map which happens to satisfy some side conditions.

Comment: @пропессор Thanks --- answer accepted!  I thought Agda would be able to do it.  Unfortunately I find even the simplest Agda impenetrable (I'm only on the nursery slopes of Haskell).  ATS looks interesting:  I'll have a go with that.

Comment: @Antal S-Z shouldn't put too much weight on the "subtype" in the pseudocode.  I might just as easily have written "refinement of".

Answer (score 26):

You can do this in Haskell with [Liquid Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Liquid_Haskell) which extends Haskell with [refinement types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_(computing)). The predicates are managed by an SMT solver at compile time which means that the proofs are fully automatic but the logic you can use is limited by what the SMT solver handles. (Happily, modern SMT solvers are reasonably versatile!)

One problem is that I don't think Liquid Haskell currently supports floats. If it doesn't though, it should be possible to rectify because there *are* theories of floating point numbers for SMT solvers. You could also pretend floating point numbers were actually rational (or even use `Rational` in Haskell!). With this in mind, your first type could look like this:

```
{p : Float | p >= 0 && p <= 1}
```

Your second type would be a bit harder to encode, especially because maps are an abstract type that's hard to reason about. If you used a list of pairs instead of a map, you could write a "measure" like this:

```
measure total :: [(a, Float)] -> Float
total []          = 0 
total ((_, p):ps) = p + probDist ps
```

(You might want to wrap `[]` in a `newtype` too.)

Now you can use `total` in a refinement to constrain a list:

```
{dist: [(a, Float)] | total dist == 1}
```

The neat trick with Liquid Haskell is that all the reasoning is automated for you at compile time, in return for using a somewhat constrained logic. (Measures like `total` are also very constrained in how they can be written—it's a small subset of Haskell with rules like "exactly one case per constructor".) This means that refinement types in this style are less powerful but much easier to use than full-on dependent types, making them more practical.

Comment: Thanks for the HT! As it happens, we've recently added support for this sort of thing, see: https://github.com/ucsd-progsys/liquidhaskell/blob/master/tests/pos/RealProps.hs

Comment: @RanjitJhala: This sort of thing being a theory of floating point? Or is it more like real numbers?

Comment: @RanjitJhala, not all of those actually hold for floating point. `inverse`, in particular, does not.

Comment: Indeed, LH uses the SMT solver's theory of real numbers (not floating point).

Answer (score 10):

Perl6 has a notion of "type subsets" which can add arbitrary conditions to create a "sub type."

For your question specifically:

```
subset Probability of Real where 0 .. 1;
```

and

```
role DPD[::T] {
  has Map[T, Probability] $.map
    where [+](.values) == 1; # calls `.values` on Map
}
```

(note: in current implementations, the "where" part is checked at run-time, but since "real types" are checked at compile-time (that includes your classes), and since there are pure annotations (`is pure`) inside the std (which is mostly perl6) (those are also on operators like `*`, etc), it's only a matter of effort put into it (and it shouldn't be much more).

More generally:

```
# (%% is the "divisible by", which we can negate, becoming "!%%")
subset Even of Int where * %% 2; # * creates a closure around its expression
subset Odd of Int where -> $n { $n !%% 2 } # using a real "closure" ("pointy block")
```

Then you can check if a number matches with the Smart Matching operator `~~`:

```
say 4 ~~ Even; # True
say 4 ~~ Odd; # False
say 5 ~~ Odd; # True
```

And, thanks to `multi sub`s (or multi whatever, really – multi methods or others), we can dispatch based on that:

```
multi say-parity(Odd $n) { say "Number $n is odd" }
multi say-parity(Even) { say "This number is even" } # we don't name the argument, we just put its type
#Also, the last semicolon in a block is optional
```

Comment: It seems every single answer has a single downvote. Don't know what conclusion to make from that though :/.

Comment: One thing I cringed at a bit was the idea that "there's nothing preventing them from being checked at compile time". The relative difference of both semantics and implementation difficulty between runtime and compile-time checking of arbitrary constraints is kind of astronomical.

Comment: One thing preventing them from being checked at compile time is that checking is undecidable.

Comment: Indeed, Perl is utterly incapable of doing the sort of thing that is intended, where the intent is inferred from the fact that the question is tagged with [tag:haskell] and [tag:agda].

Comment: @augustss checking is undecidable? You're missing a very important part of my answer here: **basic types are already checked at compile-time** (this includes classes, etc). With the correct "pure" markers (which already exist in P6 as `is pure`), there's nothing except time that prevents it from being compile-time checked now.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson ^. Well, I guess I'll rephrase my answer a little bit.

Comment: @raiph I manually applied your edit because some SO users apparently assumed that they knew P6 and your edit was wrong.

Comment: @Ven The difficulty is not (just) that your compile time checks might involve impure functions but instead that it can be difficult to prove types satisfactory/equivalent when they have arbitrary computation embedded within them. By "difficult" I'll extend that to easily undecidable if your computation is *too* general. As a simple example, you might want to try typechecking something that depends upon `P(x * 1) == P(1 * x)` for some type `P(_)`. Despite `*`'s purity and the triviality of doing that for any concrete choice of `x`... you'll find the general statement tricky to prove.

Comment: @Ven: To check a type like this, the compiler has to prove that, for every possible execution of the program, an arbitrary predicate holds. In general, this *is* undecidable, even with pure functions. You could constrain the set of possible predicates—which Perl doesn't—but it would still be extremely difficult to do, not just a matter of time. It's an open research problem! Liquid Types only manage this sort of checking because they have *very* constrained type-level predicates and use a state-of-the-art SMT solver to generate the requisite proof. That's more than just a matter of time.

Comment: We're not talking about the same thing. Here I'm just talking about compile-time checking constants (and dispatch targets based off that if possible) — I wasn't thinking of any coercing arbitrary numbers into this subtype (I definitely agree with you there, for arbitrary numbers/input, Perl6 is never going to be able to do that - not that it even tries to - and is completly unrelated to pure functions. I'm just talking about the "easy" case here, perl6 doesn't have dependant types, obviously)

Comment: @Ven I don't see how the properties that can occur I where-clauses can be checked at compile time in general.

Comment: @augustss well, they're just functions. `$_ == 1 || $_ > 5` is just calling infix<&&>, infix<==> and infix:<< > >>. Why couldn't these be called at compile-time?

Comment: @Ven Because you don't know $_ at compile time.

Comment: Of course you do. I've said multiple times that I was talking about the constant case.

Answer (score 7):

Nimrod is a new language that supports this concept. They are called Subranges. Here is an example. You can learn more about the language here [link](http://nimrod-lang.org/index.html)

```
type
  TSubrange = range[0..5]
```

Comment: Would this example definition yield a static check, or a dynamic one?

Comment: Can Nimrod to define a subset of `float`?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, yes, that would be Pascal, which has integer subranges.

Comment: Could you please include example code that shows how that is done?

Comment: Sure, although I haven't programmed in Pascal for decades. Something like VAR age: 0 ... 99;

Comment: Is it a type error at compile time to put the number 100 someplace that expects something in the range 0 to 99? If it's only a runtime error, it isn't doing what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

The [Whiley language](http://whiley.org) supports something very much like what you are saying.  For example:

```
type natural is (int x) where x >= 0
type probability is (real x) where 0.0 <= x && x <= 1.0
```

These types can also be implemented as pre-/post-conditions like so:

```
function abs(int x) => (int r)
ensures r >= 0:
    //
    if x >= 0:
        return x
    else:
        return -x
```

The language is very expressive.  These invariants and pre-/post-conditions are verified statically using an SMT solver.  This handles examples like the above very well, but currently struggles with more complex examples involving arrays and loop invariants.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I thought I'd add an example of how you might solve this in [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/) as of 2019.

The first part of the questions is straightfoward, since in the interval since since this question was asked, Nim has gained the ability to generate subrange types on floats (as well as ordinal and enum types). The code below defines two new float subranges types, `Probability` and `ProbOne`.

The second part of the question is more tricky -- defining a type with constrains on a function of it's fields. My proposed solution doesn't directly define such a type but instead uses a macro (`makePmf`) to tie the creation of a constant `Table[T,Probability]` object to the ability to create a valid `ProbOne` object (thus ensuring that the PMF is valid). The `makePmf` macro is evaluated at compile time, ensuring that you can't create an invalid PMF table.

Note that I'm a relative newcomer to Nim so this may not be the most idiomatic way to write this macro:

```
import macros, tables

type
  Probability = range[0.0 .. 1.0]
  ProbOne = range[1.0..1.0]

macro makePmf(name: untyped, tbl: untyped): untyped =
  ## Construct a Table[T, Probability] ensuring
  ## Sum(Probabilities) == 1.0

  # helper templates
  template asTable(tc: untyped): untyped =
    tc.toTable

  template asProb(f: float): untyped =
    Probability(f)

  # ensure that passed value is already is already
  # a table constructor
  tbl.expectKind nnkTableConstr
  var
    totprob: Probability = 0.0
    fval: float
    newtbl = newTree(nnkTableConstr)

  # create Table[T, Probability]
  for child in tbl:
    child.expectKind nnkExprColonExpr
    child[1].expectKind nnkFloatLit
    fval = floatVal(child[1])
    totprob += Probability(fval)
    newtbl.add(newColonExpr(child[0], getAst(asProb(fval))))

  # this serves as the check that probs sum to 1.0
  discard ProbOne(totprob)
  result = newStmtList(newConstStmt(name, getAst(asTable(newtbl))))


makePmf(uniformpmf, {"A": 0.25, "B": 0.25, "C": 0.25, "D": 0.25})

# this static block will show that the macro was evaluated at compile time
static:
  echo uniformpmf

# the following invalid PMF won't compile
# makePmf(invalidpmf, {"A": 0.25, "B": 0.25, "C": 0.25, "D": 0.15})
```

Note: A cool benefit of using a macro is that `nimsuggest` (as integrated into VS Code) will even highlight attempts to create an invalid Pmf table.

Answer (score 0):

Modula 3 has subrange types.  (Subranges of ordinals.)  So for your Example 1, if you're willing to map probability to an integer range of some precision, you could use this:

```
TYPE PROBABILITY = [0..100]
```

Add significant digits as necessary.

Ref: More about subrange ordinals [here](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/hosking/m3/reference/ordinal.html).

Comment: Is it a type error at compile time to put the number 200 someplace that expects something in the range 0 to 100? If it's only a runtime error, it isn't doing what the question is asking for.

Comment: Hi @Carl . A preference for either static or dynamic type checking is reasonable, but the question doesn't state one. From memory (I don't have an m3 system available to me right now), an assignment from superclass (e.g. `INTEGER` variable) to a subclass (e.g. `[0..100]` constrained variable) will be checked at runtime in m3.  But your example of a literal assignment of `200` to a constrained variable...  in theory it *could* or *should* be compile-time checked. I cannot say for sure, only for sure that Modula-3 *will* enforce constrained types. Hope this helps.