# Dependent Types in Elm

Tags: types, elm, dependent-type, idris

I'm wondering if it's possible to do some sort of dependent typing like the following in Elm, like you can in Idris:

```
isQuestion : String -> Type
isQuestion (sentence) with (endsWith "?" sentence)
    | True = Question
    | False = Statement
```

Is there a library that will let me achieve a similar effect via typing?

Comment: In general no, There may be a few special cases where you could fake it, but this is not a  design goal for Elm near as I can tell

Answer (score 8):

You could do something alike with union types.

```
type Sentence 
    = Question String
    | Statement String

isQuestion : String -> Sentence
isQuestion sentence =
    case endsWith "?" sentence of
        True -> Question sentence
        False -> Statement sentence
```

Comment: Well, this is not dependent types. This is just good old ADT (algebraic data type). Another question: does author really needs dependent types in his function? Probably not, and your solution is quite good.

Comment: Right, this example is way too simple to show the need for dependent types. But I would like to make type-flowing logic using type matching with a lot of different dependent types that make it easier to reason about the code. For example, a question, in plain English, is defined as a statement that ends with a question mark. It cannot be anything else. I could expand this to more definitions, such as exclamatory statement is one that ends with a exclamation mark, etc. I just wanted to be concise.

Comment: I'd enjoy being able to use [refinement types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19179441/2014893) for this sort of situation, but Union types with private constructors are quite effective.